# How to clear errors generated by INofityDataErrorInfo

Tags: wpf, mvvm, inotifydataerrorinfo

Say, I have a field `Email` and I want to show `RegEx errors` while user is typing in. But it is an optional field, so if user submits the form, this field should be cleared of any errors, and `null` value should be sent.

I have implemented `INofityDataErrorInfo` interface in my `ViewModel`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have implemented the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface correctly you should just be able to raise the `ErrorsChanged` event and make sure that the `GetErrors` method returns `null` for the `Email` property:

```
...
private readonly Dictionary<string, ICollection<string>> _validationErrors = new Dictionary<string, ICollection<string>>();

public string Email { get; set; }

public void Submit()
{
    if (_validationErrors.ContainsKey(nameof(Email)))
        _validationErrors.Remove(nameof(Email));

    RaiseErrorsChanged(nameof(Email));
    ...
}

public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;
private void RaiseErrorsChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (ErrorsChanged != null)
        ErrorsChanged(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName)
        || !_validationErrors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        return null;

    return _validationErrors[propertyName];
}

public bool HasErrors
{
    get { return _validationErrors.Count > 0; }
}
```

The `GetErrors` method will be called by the runtime when you raise the `ErrorsChanged` event.